# JPA Lazy loading works with final entities and private constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have following entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public final class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "VEHICLE_ID")
    private int vehicleId;

    @Column(name = "MANUFACTURER")
    private String manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
    private Person person;
    //private constructor
    private  Vehicle() { }
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(PERSON)
public final class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    int personId;
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    //constructor is private
    private Person() {
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

and here is my test class

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("vehiclePU");
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

        Person person = entityManager.find(Person.class, 0);
        System.out.println("person = " + person);
        person.getVehicles().forEach(System.out::println);

        emf.close();


    }
}
```

My question are

1. Why its allowing to declare entity as final and with private no arg constructor since as per JPA specs this is not allowed?
2. I understand that for lazy loading hibernate uses proxy objects, and proxy objects are nothing but the subclass of entities, but since here both the entities are declared as final how its allowing them to be sub classed?

I am also wondering how lazy loading works? and which proxy library Hibernate uses by default, and how can we get to know it which library its using?

I am using Hibernate 5 and JPA 2.1.

Comment: The JPA spec says ... for portability the default constructor should not be private. Nothing more, if the implementation wants to support private, then it can, but the user cannot rely on it in other implementations. The CLASS can be final. The fields/methods can't ... for portability.

Comment: @NeilStockton how its allowing proxies and lazy loading?

Comment: since I don't use Hibernate and that is a Hibernate specific option, others can answer it. Not all implementations use "proxies", some use wrappers, and detect such tings via bytecode enhancement.

Comment: @NeilStockton can you please share the link where you found jpa Spec?

Comment: This page has a link, near the bottom http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neil said: it is not required to support final classes with private constructors - but it is not forbidden.

But besides the facts that you loose provider independence and that you will see warnings by any JPA validator - you will *loose lazy loading, too*.

You did talk about lazy loading, but your example does *not* make use of it. The following will work for a public non-final `Person` class with public or protected noargs constructors:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person person;
```

But as the JavaDoc for `fetch` says:

> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that the associated entity must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.

So Hibernate does not complain about a wrong `LAZY` - but it will silently ignore if something prevents lazy loading. For example a final class, or a private no args constructor or `optional=true` (the default) without bytecode enhancement.

You can see all of that by playing with the different options and checking the Hibernate log (check for `load` commands) and by using `vehicle.getPerson().getClass()`.

As soon as you've got lazy loading working and receive a proxy class you can see the library that is used by Hibernate as well: *Javassist*

Comment: How can I make it to use cglib for proxy class generation?

Comment: It is deprecated and not maintained anymore, but depending on your version you can still use it with  
`-Dhibernate.bytecode.provider=cglib` (Rule of thumb: Search first, ask later)

Comment: I checked the in Hibernate 5 source now its not possible even to use cglib, they completely removed it. 
I already tried the property that you mentioned but it wasn't using cglib anymore then I realized after checking source that cglib is not used anymore with hibernate 5.  thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thats what I meant with _depending on your version_. Just of curiosity: What would be the benefit to use the outdated cglib here?